# How do I add properties to ng.Iscope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm accessing a scope like so:

```
  let element = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('active'));
  let scope = element.scope();
```

And my scope object looks like this when I do a

```
console.log(scope);
```

> `$id:2017
>   $parent:ChildScope
>   $root:Scope
>   __private__:Object
>   index:0
>   match:Object
>   __proto__:Object`

However when I try to do:

```
console.log(scope.match);
```

Typescript gives a syntax error:

> (27,34): error TS2339: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'IScope'.

And printing out scope.$id works

```
console.log(scope.$id);
```

I know it has something to do $id being defined in the docs so that works. http://definitelytyped.org/docs/angularjs--angular-route/interfaces/ng.iscope.html

How would I print out my member variable `scope.match` without getting a Typescript error?  I think I would need to extend ng.IScope?

Comment: It sounds like the property `match` isn't added to the scope at the time of the console log. Could you add a minimal working example?

Comment: Is it possible to check for a scope property?
`if (scope.match == null)` doesn't work because of error TS2339.

Comment: You can always use `if (angular.isUndefined(scope.match))` but you should really figure out why you are trying to access a property when it isn't there yet.

Comment: I tried `isUndefined()` and I get the same error doing `scope.match`

Comment: Again I can't really help you if i don't have a example that can reproduce your problem..

Comment: I created a little [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jutLdjb2/2/) that shows how `angular.isDefined` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by exporting an interface and then casting ng.IScope.

Make sure to use **?** to make it an optional parameter.  That's where I went wrong

```
export interface IMyScope extends ng.IScope {
  match?: any;
}
```

And then:

```
let myScope = <IMyScope>element.scope();
```